# How to optimize the below query and what is (Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)) With EXPLAIN

Tags: mysql, optimization, mysql-5.6

I have been facing an issue with the query. whenever I try to select the query it taking 10 to 15 seconds to execute. and what is (Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)) in the explain

The query is

```
SELECT  wp_posts.ID, post_title, post_content, wp_pvc_total.postcount,
        wp_pvc_total.postnum
    FROM  wp_posts
    LEFT JOIN  wp_term_relationships
          ON ( wp_posts.ID =
               wp_term_relationships.object_id )
    LEFT JOIN  wp_term_taxonomy
          ON ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id =
               wp_term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id )
    LEFT JOIN  wp_pvc_total  ON ( wp_pvc_total.postnum = wp_posts.ID )
    WHERE  wp_posts.post_author = 630
      AND  wp_posts.post_author NOT IN(675)
      AND  wp_posts.ID != 48075
    GROUP BY  wp_posts.ID
    ORDER BY  wp_pvc_total.postcount DESC
    LIMIT  0, 9;
```

Query with explain

```
+----+-------------+-----------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table                 | type   | possible_keys                                                             | key         | key_len | ref                                                   | rows  | Extra                                                  |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | wp_posts              | range  | PRIMARY,post_name,type_status_date,post_parent,post_author,idx_post_title | post_author | 16      | NULL                                                  |  1682 | Using index condition; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | wp_term_relationships | ref    | PRIMARY                                                                   | PRIMARY     | 8       | marriai1_topic.wp_posts.ID                            |     1 | Using index                                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | wp_term_taxonomy      | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                                   | PRIMARY     | 8       | marriai1_topic.wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id |     1 | Using index                                            |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | wp_pvc_total          | ALL    | NULL                                                                      | NULL        | NULL    | NULL                                                  | 19670 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)     |
+----+-------------+-----------------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------+-------------------------------------------------------+-------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

The MySQL Version is 5.6, Innodb Engine and The table structures are

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_posts` (
  `ID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_author` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_date_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content` longtext NOT NULL,
  `post_title` text NOT NULL,
  `post_excerpt` text NOT NULL,
  `post_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'publish',
  `comment_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `ping_status` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'open',
  `post_password` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `post_name` varchar(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `to_ping` text NOT NULL,
  `pinged` text NOT NULL,
  `post_modified` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_modified_gmt` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `post_content_filtered` longtext NOT NULL,
  `post_parent` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `guid` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `menu_order` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `post_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'post',
  `post_mime_type` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `comment_count` bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `post_name` (`post_name`(191)),
  KEY `type_status_date` (`post_type`,`post_status`,`post_date`,`ID`),
  KEY `post_parent` (`post_parent`),
  KEY `post_author` (`post_author`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `idx_post_title` (`post_title`)
)
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE `wp_pvc_total` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `postnum` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `postcount` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '750',
  UNIQUE KEY `id` (`id`)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `INDEX(postnum, postcount)`

That will make reaching into `wp_pvc_total` more efficient.  And it is "covering".

BNL is quite efficient, so I am no sure that this index will be better.  But it seems like having no useful index is inefficient.

On a separate issue, KEY `post_name` (`post_name`(191)) is problematic.  See http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes

Comment: Hello Rick, Thanks for the suggestion. has you said above index is not working and the problematic key post_name I have to change the index to the normal state like post_name(post_name). but I didn't get any solution for it. Can you please investigate deeper for me. 
Thank you

Comment: @Niroopchowdary - Please edit the Question (or add a Comment here) to show the current indexes.